# Get BIM 360 Docs Project and Plans Folders

Tags: rest, autodesk-forge

Sounds like an easy question right?

I want to the ID of the 2 ROOT Folders of BIM360 Docs.
The Plans & Project Folders.

2 Problems.... :(

The first is the ROOT Folders can be renamed inside of BIM360 Docs, so I can look by name or string value. (in the case of the renamed ROOT Folder it is renamed in the NAME and DISPLAYNAME)

The Second is if you use GetTopLevel Folder from Data Management API it gives me all the hidden folders as well.

So the automatic response is to say why not use the attributes of the folders and ignore the hidden folders....... low and behold the attributes of all folders are all set HIDDEN = False.  Although clearly some of the folders do not appear in BIM360 Docs, so must be hidden another way.

[image: All Hidden Folders]

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.
Happy New Year.

Comment: Do you recognize the additional folders (_ProjectTb_, _Photos_)? Are those subfolders somewhere in your BIM360 Docs? Have you tried filtering the folders based on their parent, using `relationships.parent.data.id`?

Comment: These are Folder that are hidden inside of BIM360 Docs, I am guessing these are folders that Autodesk use.

Comment: @PetrBroz how does the relationships.parent.data.id help me the Project files folder?

Comment: I was wondering where those folders came from because I don't see them when querying my own BIM360 Docs project.

Comment: Regarding the `relationships.parent.data.id`, I was thinking that perhaps the _ProjectTb_ and _Photos_ folders would not have the same parent ID as _Project Files_ or _Plans_. In that case you could use this information to filter out the unneeded folders.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling the [top folders API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-project_id-topFolders-GET/) with an [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant access token](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) ("three-legged" token) you should be getting only the "Plans" and "Project Files" folders

Request:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_JWT_TOKEN" 
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.hub.id.123/projects/b.project.id.xyz/topFolders"
```

Response:

```
{
"jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
},
"links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.hub.id.123/projects/b.project.id.xyz/topFolders"
    }
},
"data": [
    {
        "type": "folders",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.CpjEV04YT_WDKXRkK5uiEg",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Plans",
            "displayName": "Plans",
            "createTime": "2017-06-26T09:27:39.0000000Z",
            "createUserId": "",
            "createUserName": "",
            "lastModifiedTime": "2017-06-26T09:27:39.0000000Z",
            "lastModifiedUserId": "",
            "lastModifiedUserName": "",
            "lastModifiedTimeRollup": "2017-06-26T09:27:39.0000000Z",
            "objectCount": 0,
            "hidden": false,
            "extension": {
                "type": "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder",
                "version": "1.0",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder-1.0"
                },
                "data": {
                    "visibleTypes": [
                        "items:autodesk.bim360:Document"
                    ],
                    "actions": [
                        "CONVERT",
                        "SPLIT",
                        "OCR"
                    ],
                    "allowedTypes": [
                        "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder",
                        "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
                        "items:autodesk.bim360:Document",
                        "items:autodesk.bim360:TitleBlock",
                        "items:autodesk.bim360:ReviewDocument"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.CpjEV04YT_WDKXRkK5uiEg"
            }
        },
        "relationships": {
            "contents": {
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.CpjEV04YT_WDKXRkK5uiEg/contents"
                    }
                }
            },
            "parent": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "folders",
                    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.8w-SI-ggRAuTQcTlD0GK6g"
                },
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.CpjEV04YT_WDKXRkK5uiEg/parent"
                    }
                }
            },
            "refs": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.CpjEV04YT_WDKXRkK5uiEg/relationships/refs"
                    },
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.CpjEV04YT_WDKXRkK5uiEg/refs"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.CpjEV04YT_WDKXRkK5uiEg/relationships/links"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "folders",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.q7ElPL9HRTSpVuMP5-xq7w",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Project Files",
            "displayName": "Project Files",
            "createTime": "2017-06-26T09:27:41.0000000Z",
            "createUserId": "",
            "createUserName": "",
            "lastModifiedTime": "2017-11-08T13:06:58.0000000Z",
            "lastModifiedUserId": "XXXXXXXX",
            "lastModifiedUserName": "John%20Smith",
            "lastModifiedTimeRollup": "2018-01-10T09:09:36.0000000Z",
            "objectCount": 6,
            "hidden": false,
            "extension": {
                "type": "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder",
                "version": "1.0",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder-1.0"
                },
                "data": {
                    "visibleTypes": [
                        "items:autodesk.bim360:File"
                    ],
                    "actions": [
                        "CONVERT"
                    ],
                    "allowedTypes": [
                        "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
                        "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.q7ElPL9HRTSpVuMP5-xq7w"
            }
        },
        "relationships": {
            "contents": {
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.q7ElPL9HRTSpVuMP5-xq7w/contents"
                    }
                }
            },
            "parent": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "folders",
                    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.8w-SI-ggRAuTQcTlD0GK6g"
                },
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.q7ElPL9HRTSpVuMP5-xq7w/parent"
                    }
                }
            },
            "refs": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.q7ElPL9HRTSpVuMP5-xq7w/relationships/refs"
                    },
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.q7ElPL9HRTSpVuMP5-xq7w/refs"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.project.id.xyz/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.q7ElPL9HRTSpVuMP5-xq7w/relationships/links"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I need to use 2 legged as the code is running in windows service.